# Why I am getting TLE at CSES problem "Book Shop" of dynamic programming

Tags: c++17

TLE

[image]

I am getting the same error in case of coin combination 2

[link to the problem](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1158)

Failed tc

[image]

```
//*******************************************

// Code by:
//       *                   *
//      * *                 * *
//     *****               *****
//    *     *             *     *
//   *       *arushi     *       * garwal

//*******************************************

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define fastio()                      \
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); \
    cin.tie(NULL);
#define yes cout << "YES\n"
#define no cout << "NO\n"
#define MOD 1000000007
#define endl "\n"
#define MOD1 998244353
#define INF 1e18
#define nline "\n"
#define pb push_back
#define ppb pop_back
#define mp make_pair
#define ff first
#define ss second
#define PI 3.141592653589793238462
#define set_bits __builtin_popcountll
#define sz(x) ((int)(x).size())
#define all(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()
#define for0 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
#define for1 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
#define forr for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)

typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long long ull;
typedef long double lld;
// typedef tree<pair<int, int>, null_type, less<pair<int, int>>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update > pbds; // find_by_order, order_of_key

#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
#define debug(x)       \
    cerr << #x << " "; \
    _print(x);         \
    cerr << endl;
#else
#define debug(x)
#endif

void _print(ll t)
{
    cerr << t;
}
void _print(int t) { cerr << t; }
void _print(string t) { cerr << t; }
void _print(char t) { cerr << t; }
void _print(lld t) { cerr << t; }
void _print(double t) { cerr << t; }
void _print(ull t) { cerr << t; }

template <class T, class V>
void _print(pair<T, V> p);
template <class T>
void _print(vector<T> v);
template <class T>
void _print(set<T> v);
template <class T, class V>
void _print(map<T, V> v);
template <class T>
void _print(multiset<T> v);
template <class T, class V>
void _print(pair<T, V> p)
{
    cerr << "{";
    _print(p.ff);
    cerr << ",";
    _print(p.ss);
    cerr << "}";
}
template <class T>
void _print(vector<T> v)
{
    cerr << "[ ";
    for (T i : v)
    {
        _print(i);
        cerr << " ";
    }
    cerr << "]";
}
template <class T>
void _print(set<T> v)
{
    cerr << "[ ";
    for (T i : v)
    {
        _print(i);
        cerr << " ";
    }
    cerr << "]";
}
template <class T>
void _print(multiset<T> v)
{
    cerr << "[ ";
    for (T i : v)
    {
        _print(i);
        cerr << " ";
    }
    cerr << "]";
}
template <class T, class V>
void _print(map<T, V> v)
{
    cerr << "[ ";
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        _print(i);
        cerr << " ";
    }
    cerr << "]";
}

// EVERY SINGLE QUES TAKES YOU TOWARDS YOUR GOAL :)
// ********************************************************

int i, t, j, sum, n, ans, k;
const int M = 1e9 + 7;
const int N = 1e5;
int dp[1001][N + 1];
ll binExp(ll a, ll b)
{
    ll result = 1;
    while (b > 0)
    {
        if (b & 1)
            result = (result * a) % M;
        a = (a * a) % M;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
int fun(int i, int price[], int pages[], int cost)
{
    if (i < 0)
        return 0;
    if (cost == 0)
        return 0;
    if (dp[i][cost] != -1)
        return dp[i][cost];
    int ans = fun(i - 1, price, pages, cost);
    if (cost >= price[i])
        ans = max(ans, fun(i - 1, price, pages, cost - price[i]) + pages[i]);
    return dp[i][cost] = ans;
}
void hacked()
{
    // cin>>n;
    // string s;
    // cin>>s;

    cin >> n >> sum;
    int price[n];
    int pages[n];

    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> price[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> pages[i];
    }
    cout << fun(n - 1, price, pages, sum) << endl;
}
int main()
{
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("Error.txt", "w", stderr);
#endif
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    hacked();
    return 0;
}`
```

I tried using int instead of long long but still getting tle.

> You are in a book shop which sells n different books. You know the
> price and number of pages of each book.
>
> You have decided that the total price of your purchases will be at
> most x. What is the maximum number of pages you can buy? You can buy
> each book at most once.

Comment: Please remove the nonsense up to `fun` and post the input output example as **text**, questions should provide a [mre]. Also note that `price` and `pages` are declared as Variable Length Arrays, which aren't standard C++, but are only provided by some compilers as an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because of the auxiliary space used up by top-down approach - the recursive stack- bottom-up works tho.

UPD: I just read  this [CF BLOG](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/86102), people mention about the strict constraints of CSES, so it's better to solve using bottom-up.